# Android: AmazingListView Pinned Header is Untouchable

Tags: android, listview, button, togglebutton

I have a project that uses AmazingListView:

https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

I need for the pinned header to have a clickable button. However, it appears that the pinned header for some reason can't receive any touch events. What do I have to do make this button clickable? Is there some way to intercept the events and send them to the header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same problem with this component. 
In my case the pinned header is a relativelayout that has a button that I need to use.
The actual problem lies in the way the pinned header is added to the listview.
It is "drawn" rather than added to the listview hierachy:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    if (mHeaderViewVisible) {
        drawChild(canvas, mHeaderView, getDrawingTime());
    }
}
```

mHeaderView is never added to the view hierachy...

I don't know if it is possible for views that are "drawn" this away to receive any user input.

Maybe we need to work out a way to implement the pinned header by adding it to the view hierachy...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you will need to override some methods on the AmazingAdapter, if I recall correctly, by default those views are treated as not Enabled. See ListAdapter and it's methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

So, in theory (I haven't studied deeply the code for AmazingListView) you should return true for those elements or just return true for all.

Comment: Tried overriding those methods and return true but had no luck... it seems drawn views that are not added to the hierarchy dont get user input...